Bootstrapping Par Curves from Spot and their values with respect to each other
Context
I am trying to code a general algorithm to 'convert' a spot curve to a par curve for any given curve. This is part of a larger problem - where I need to calculate par rate for any given spot curve and for any given tenor.
Consider the following instance of a spot curve (completely hypothetical):



Tenor
Spot




1mo
1%


40d
1.5%


3mo
2.0%


120d
2.5%


1y
5%


2y
8.5%


3y
10%


10y
18.25%



Problem
When I try to code using the calculation methodology as below, my results for par curves at the 10 year tenor is higher than the spot curve rate. However the problem gets solved if I change the last tenor from 10yr to 4yr.
Following are my numbers for par curve:



Tenor
Spot




1mo
0.9954%


40d
1.4901%


3mo
1.9852%


120d
2.4795%


1y
5%


2y
8.3551%


3y
9.7403%


10y
29.67%



CALCULATION METHOD

For tenors upto 1year, I am using the following formula:

$par(N)$ = $\frac {1-df(N)}{df_{N}} *\frac{360}{N}$

For tenors greater than 1 yr I am calculating the par rate for each tenor by the following formula (assuming $1 notional):

$par(N)$ = $\frac {1-df(N)}{\sum_{i=1y}^{N} df_{i}}$
$df(i)$ is the discount factor calculated using the spot rate for that period. For example, using the spot rate as above:
$df(1y) \approx 0.952381$ (calculated by $\frac{1}{(1+r)^{t}}$, where t is in years)
I am having a hunch that my formulas are wrong (even though I derived it myself and not sure where I am exactly wrong), or my "basic" knowledge of bootstrapping is wrong. Please help.

For clarity what you refer to as "spot" are a measure of rates akin to YTM or IRR calculations (from the definition of your derived discount factors). They are not continuously compounded zero coupon rates. Your "par" rates seem to be equivalent of interest rate swap rates, again looking at the definition of your formula. Many people, particularly in the derivatives world, would interpret "spot" rates and "par" rates as both being the same thing, i.e. swap rate. It is often better to be more specific to avoid ambiguities.

You are right. I am using par curve in the context that it is a swap curve on (risk-free) government bond instruments. My understanding of this entirely comes from my CFA L2 Fixed Income Module :)

Your formula are not wrong but you can clearly see that $\sum df_i$ requires the discount factors for every year until 10y. You have neglected to state how you derive these for the intermediate points between 3y and 10y. Hint: you need to use some method of interpolation. When you switch "10y" to "4y" it works because you no longer need interpolation.

Ah I see. So I have to interpolate first and then calculate the par rate. thank you!
